# Start Application_Start again on a shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax, shared-hosting, application-start

I  am on a shared hosting plan using asp.net mvc 3. In my Application_Start I start my Quartz scheduler and have some jobs run. However some don't seem to be running or something is wrong in them(but they don't seem to throw errors).

I been reuploading all my .dll's for my project but I am not 100% sure if that restarts the Application_Start().

So how do I ensure that Application_Start() gets rerun?

Comment: Writer a log or send an email from the Application_Start. Updating the dll and web.config would cause the application restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-uploading any assembly in the `bin` folder will restart the application and on the next request `Application_Start` will be run again. Another condition when this will happen is if you upload only the `~/web.config` file or the `~/Global.asax` (be careful with this one as if you are using a precompiled web application make sure to pick the correct one).